# How does Hangouts get desktop capture on Safari?

Tags: safari, webrtc, google-hangouts, get-display-media

So if we have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API

The state of the `getDisplayMedia` - the function used to get desktop stream - shows that its currently not supported in safari 12. And its evident from the fact that calling `getDisplayMedia` in the console on Safari tells us that its not available.

Then how is it that Google Hangouts is able to get the desktop share in safari? Since hangouts is running inside the browser and according to my knowledge it has to use JS APIs to get screen.

Any hint or help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`getDisplayMedia` ***is*** supported in Safari 13. The MDN page you link to even [says so](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API#Browser_compatibility).

This is what Hangouts uses. You can try it out [here](https://jan-ivar.github.io/dummy/gdm.html) (click the "User gesture" button).

Safari only offers to share the entire desktop at the moment.

Comment: Unless you meant Safari on iOS?

Comment: It is supported in Safari 13 I have checked. But I've been using hangouts on 12.1.1 And that is what I can't understand. Does it use some browser extension???? 

But even if it did use an extension, it would not be able to add a getDisplay media API would it??